# How to have char like 'char *name[]' in C?

Tags: c, char

I am writing a Windows API application called List Maker in C.

I have a struct for list data that looks like this:

```
typedef struct LMLIST
{
    LPSTR filename;
    char title[128];
    char author[128];
    BOOL openSuccess;
    char *contents[];
    int numLines;


}LMLIST;
```

However, the compiler complains that:

```
Error   1   error C2229: struct 'LMLIST' has an illegal zero-sized array    c:\users\ian duncan\documents\github\listmakerforwindows\listmakerforwindows\listmakerlist.h    11  1   ListMakerForWindows
```

Which refers to `char *contents[]`.

My idea was to have a char array, with each item being a list item, like this:

```
[0] List Item 1
[1] List Item 2
[2] List Item 3
...
```

Much like `char *argv[]`

Is this possible, and if not, is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `char **contents` and allocate the array of character pointers dynamically:

```
LMLIST x;
...
x.contents = malloc(numstrings * sizeof (char *));
```

If you are not storing the number of strings elsewhere, you will need to add one to the number of strings to make room for the terminating NULL pointer:

```
x.contents = malloc((numstrings + 1) * sizeof (char *));
x.contents[numstrings] = NULL;
```

This is in essence how `argv` gets allocated.

Answer (score 3):

Use a  `char **` and use `malloc` to allocate your array member.